# how to estimate the SNR with limited knowledge of the signal

Tags: python, signal-processing, noise, signal-strength

I have a signal that I'm trying to determine the SNR of, but I have limited knowledge of the signal. For the signal that I'm receiving I don't know what the frequency will be, but I do know that frequency won't change. I know that my signal is broken into blocks (symbols), and that the phase difference between any two blocks will either be 0 or 180 degrees. I also know that the signals will have similar amplitudes, so the only thing different between any two blocks of signals should be the phase and whatever noise is affecting them.

As for the noise that's added to the signal, I'm expecting most of it to be awgn, but there could be intersymbol interference as well, which would be noise at the same frequency as the signal itself.

Is there a way to determine the SNR with only this information? Here's an example. I can generate the two blocks of signals, called prevSig and currSig, and that's what might be transmitted.

[image]

Then when receiving the signal, some random noise will be added and those same signals can be seen as:

[image]

So if i only have the noisy received signals, what can I do to get the SNR from these. I believe I can determine the relative phase between any two blocks of signals by doing a point-wise addition or subtraction of the samples. if adding the samples together is smaller than subtracting the samples, then that would mean the blocks have a relative phase difference of 180, and if it's not then the blocks have the same phase, so from there I can easily get two blocks of signals that should be the same initial signal just with different random noises affecting them (I'm assuming the noise variance will be similar though)

Thanks for helping me think through this. Below is the code I used to generate these signals

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

fs = 12000
t = 505/fs
f = 500
samples = np.arange(t * fs) / fs
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * samples)

prevSig = signal
currSig = signal*-1 # 180 degree phase shift
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=list(prevSig), mode='lines+markers', name='prevSig'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=list(currSig), mode='lines+markers', name='currSig'), row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(dict(title=dict(text='Signals before noise')))
fig.show()

#calculate power of signal before noise
sigPower = np.mean(signal**2)

targetSNR = 5

#Calculate noise
prevNoise = np.random.normal(0, sigPower/targetSNR, len(signal))
currNoise = np.random.normal(0, sigPower/targetSNR, len(signal))

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=list(prevSig+prevNoise), mode='lines+markers', name='prevSigNoisy'), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=list(currSig+currNoise), mode='lines+markers', name='currSigNoisy'), row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(dict(title=dict(text='Signals with noise')))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Well, you could FFT the signal. Keep the dominant few components as "signal", the rest as "noise". Use the squared amplitudes of the Fourier coefficients as a measure of the energy in that frequency component, summing these to get total amount of "signal" or "noise". Alternatively, since your signal looks pretty monochrome you could just average the zero-crossings to get the half-period and thence main  frequency.

Comment: For the application this is being used for, i'm not sure that we'll have the time and memory to do a large enough fft to single out the frequency. Also, one thing that isn't mentioned here (and I'll add it) is there could be some intersymbol interference, which would be an additional noise source which is at the same frequency as the signal

Comment: you can do fft on parts of the signal and do the same. BTW, what's the length/duration of the signal? Will it keep same phase and frequency the whole time (if not, splitting signal into chunks is a must, I guess)?

Comment: by doing the FFT on parts of the signal, do you mean like a DFT where i'm only calculating specific bins, or just on a smaller section of the signal itself? 

as for the duration of the signal, it will vary with the size of the data that's being transmitted by it, but it will be at least 150-200 symbols/blocks, and the frequency will be the same the whole time, but the phase will vary with the data, but each symbol/block will have the same phase throughout

Answer (score 3):

Let's take your signal:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft

fs = 12000
t = 505/fs
f = 500
samples = np.arange(t * fs) / fs
signal = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * samples)
```

And add some reproducible noise on it:

```
np.random.seed(12345)
noise = 0.25*np.random.normal(size=signal.size)
```

Then we can estimate SNR by estimating RMS of each component:

```
def rms(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2)/x.size)

SNR = (rms(signal)/rms(noise))**2  # 7.76816527364244
```

Now let's confirm it can be estimated using FFT by denoising your signal.

We take the FFT of the noise signal (and also compute frequencies for plotting sake):

```
dt = np.diff(samples)[0]  # 1/f
G = fft.fft(signal + noise)
freq = fft.fftfreq(G.size, dt)
```

Now we create a numerical filter (hat filter) that will only pick up or reject the base frequency:

```
q = np.abs(np.abs(freq) - f) <= 20.
F = np.zeros(G.size)
F[q] = 1.
```

We filter signals:

```
Gf = G*F
Nf = G*(1-F)
```

[image]

And estimate Power and then SNR:

```
def power(X):
    return np.sum(np.real(X*np.conj(X)))

SNR2 = power(Gf)/power(Nf)  # 7.600875978410159
```

Which is compliant our reference.

We can confirm our filtered signal is properly denoised by taking the inverse FFT:

```
signalf = np.real(fft.ifft(Gf))
```

[image]

Provided you have enough capacity to preform FFT, your signal is sufficiently clean and simple to estimate SNR from FFT.